# Clickable background ads in wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, ads

I'm modifying a wordpress theme, but I can't really figure out how I can make each part( left, right, top) of the background clickable and add some ad banners there.

Could anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com . SO is more about programming questions as opposed to WP theme development.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to place each ad in div. In most cases this ads point to some external sites(the ads are links so they're clickable).